# Using Esri Web AppBuilder Directions Widgets

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-portal

I have a road network which I published on ArcGIS portal. The road network is working fine on ArcMap and when I published it is working fine using ArcGIS REST API directly (.../RoadNetwork/NAServer/Route/).

I am having issues while configuring the directions widget in Web AppBuilder (2.13 or before).

Travel Mode URL is giving me suggestion to add a GP Service why should I use a GP Service when I have the option to retrieve travel mode using ArcGIS rest API (..../RoadNetwork/NAServer/Route/retrieveTravelModes/) does this mean I have to publish a GP Service ?

I am not giving anything in Travel Mode URL option and When I configure the widget and run the directions I am getting following error in console.

[image]

What I am doing wrong ?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved now.  The issue was that I was getting wrong travel modes from my service itself and since these travel modes were not actually defined in my network so they were causing this issue.

I was getting wrong travel modes due to the face i am running this on a ArcGIS portal where we had a default setting due to which the travel modes were getting overridden with the actual ones which i defined.

I have to remove the default settings of portal (Under Organization -> Utility Services -> Directions and Routing -> Routing Utilities URL)

Now when I removed this from our staging portal I am getting the correct travel modes and the widget is working as well.